# Insert an element at a specific index in a list and return the updated list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, insert

I have this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> print a
[1, 2, 4]

>>> print a.insert(2, 3)
None

>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> b = a.insert(3, 6)
>>> print b
None

>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4]
```

Is there a way I can get the updated list as the result, instead of updating the original list in place?

Comment: @mkoistinen It doesn't work for me. `>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a[:].insert(2, 5)
>>> print b
None`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The shortest I got: `b = a[:2] + [3] + a[2:]`

```
>>>
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> print a
[1, 2, 4]
>>> b = a[:2] + [3] + a[2:]
>>> print a
[1, 2, 4]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Number of lines of code is not a good measure of code quality. This approach is flawed for both performance and readability reasons.

Comment: can we do `a= a[:2] + [3] + a[2:]`?

Comment: @a_guest I think it's very readable.

Answer (score 131):

`l.insert(index, obj)` doesn't actually return anything. It just updates the list.

As ATO said, you can do `b = a[:index] + [obj] + a[index:]`.
However, another way is:

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = a[:]
b.insert(2, 3)
```

Comment: If you can't tolerate 3 lines of readable code, put it in a function and call it.

Answer (score 109):

### Most performance efficient approach

You may also insert the element using the *slice indexing* in the list. For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> insert_at = 2  # Index at which you want to insert item

>>> b = a[:]   # Created copy of list "a" as "b".
               # Skip this step if you are ok with modifying the original list

>>> b[insert_at:insert_at] = [3]  # Insert "3" within "b"
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For **inserting multiple elements together at a given index**, all you need to do is to use a `list` of multiple elements that you want to insert. For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> insert_at = 2   # Index starting from which multiple elements will be inserted

# List of elements that you want to insert together at "index_at" (above) position
>>> insert_elements = [3, 5, 6]

>>> a[insert_at:insert_at] = insert_elements
>>> a   # [3, 5, 6] are inserted together in `a` starting at index "2"
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
```

To know more about *slice indexing*, you can refer: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2063361).

**Note:** In Python 3.x, difference of performance between *slice indexing* and *`list.index(...)`* is significantly reduced and both are almost equivalent. However, in Python 2.x, this difference is quite noticeable. I have shared performance comparisons later in this answer.

---

**Alternative using list comprehension** *(but very slow in terms of performance)*:

As an alternative, it can be achieved using *list comprehension* with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) too. *(But please don't do it this way. It is just for illustration)*:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> insert_at = 2

>>> b = [y for i, x in enumerate(a) for y in ((3, x) if i == insert_at else (x, ))]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

### Performance comparison of all solutions

Here's the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) comparison of all the answers with list of 1000 elements on Python 3.9.1 and Python 2.7.16. Answers are listed in the order of performance for both the Python versions.

#### Python 3.9.1

1. [*My answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139870/2063361) using sliced insertion - Fastest *( 2.25 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python3 -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:]; b[500:500] = [3]"
   100000 loops, best of 5: 2.25 µsec per loop
   ```
2. [*Rushy Panchal's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895767/2063361) with most votes using `list.insert(...)`- Second *(2.33 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python3 -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:]; b.insert(500, 3)"
   100000 loops, best of 5: 2.33 µsec per loop
   ```
3. [*ATOzTOA's accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895600/2063361) based on merge of sliced lists - Third *(5.01 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python3 -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:500] + [3] + a[500:]"
   50000 loops, best of 5: 5.01 µsec per loop
   ```
4. [*My answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139870/2063361) with *List Comprehension* and `enumerate` - Fourth *(very slow with 135 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python3 -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "[y for i, x in enumerate(a) for y in ((3, x) if i == 500 else (x, )) ]"
   2000 loops, best of 5: 135 µsec per loop
   ```

#### Python 2.7.16

1. [*My answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139870/2063361) using sliced insertion - Fastest *(2.09 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:]; b[500:500] = [3]"
   100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 µsec per loop
   ```
2. [*Rushy Panchal's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895767/2063361) with most votes using `list.insert(...)`- Second *(2.36 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:]; b.insert(500, 3)"
   100000 loops, best of 3: 2.36 µsec per loop
   ```
3. [*ATOzTOA's accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895600/2063361) based on merge of sliced lists - Third *(4.44 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a[:500] + [3] + a[500:]"
   100000 loops, best of 3: 4.44 µsec per loop
   ```
4. [*My answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139870/2063361) with *List Comprehension* and `enumerate` - Fourth *(very slow with 103 µsec per loop)*

   ```
   python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "[y for i, x in enumerate(a) for y in ((3, x) if i == 500 else (x, )) ]"
   10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µsec per loop
   ```

Comment: I really like this result because it easily extends to solve the problem, what if I want to insert the values `3, 3.5` into that list (in order) -> `a[2:2] = [3,3.5]`. Very neat

Comment: This solution is better than the chosen one

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest approach is to copy the list and then insert the object into the copy. On Python 3 this can be done via `list.copy`:

```py
new = old.copy()
new.insert(index, value)
```

On Python 2 copying the list can be achieved via `new = old[:]` (this also works on Python 3).

In terms of performance there is no difference to other proposed methods:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.1
$ python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a.copy(); b.insert(500, 3)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.84 µsec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1000))" "b = a.copy(); b[500:500] = (3,)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.76 µsec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to add a single item, a single item in specific index concatenate list with another list

```
>>> expences = [2200, 2350, 2600, 2130, 2190]
>>> expences.append(1980)
>>> expences
[2200, 2350, 2600, 2130, 2190, 1980]

>>> expences.insert(1, 1200)

>>> expences
[2200, 1200, 2350, 2600, 2130, 2190, 1980]

>>> newElm = [2550, 2123, 2430]
>>> expences.extend(newElm)
>>> expences
[2200, 1200, 2350, 2600, 2130, 2190, 1980, 2550, 2123, 2430]
>>>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the [Python list insert() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm). Usage:

> #Syntax

> The syntax for the insert() method −

> `list.insert(index, obj)`

> #Parameters

- index − This is the Index where the object obj need to be inserted.
- obj − This is the Object to be inserted into the given list.

> #Return Value
> This method does not return any value, but it inserts the given element at the given index.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,4,5]

a.insert(2,3)

print(a)
```

Returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Question was specific: `Is there anyway I can get the updated list as result, instead of updating the original list in place?` Your answer does the opposite.