# Appending new items to a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append

How do you append a string to a list of strings, particularly, to a specific string in the list?

For example:

```
myList = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

newString = 'peach'
```

I want to append newString to index 1 ('oranges') of myList (so that the newString appears after index 1 in myList.) How would I go about doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert an element at specific index in a list and return updated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-updated-list)

Comment: next time, please search before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inbuilt method for lists known as `.insert()` which takes 2 arguments , first being the position and the other the object you want to insert, So the code may look like:

```
myList = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

newString = 'peach'

position = 1

myList.insert(position, newString)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=insert#mutable-sequence-types):

```
In [3]: myList = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

In [4]: myList.insert(1, 'peach')

In [5]: myList
Out[5]: ['apples', 'peach', 'oranges', 'bananas']
```

*1* is the position, *'peach'* is the element to insert.

Answer (score 4):

There are two common ways to do this.

1. Use [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=insert#mutable-sequence-types) method, like this

   ```
   >>> myList.insert(1, newString)
   >>> myList
   ['apples', 'peach', 'oranges', 'bananas']
   ```
2. Use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1903116) to assign an element to the slice 1:1, like this

   ```
   >>> myList[1:1] = [newString]
   >>> myList
   ['apples', 'peach', 'oranges', 'bananas']
   ```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=insert#mutable-sequence-types),

> `s.insert(i, x)`   same as `s[i:i] = [x]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `list.append` method:

```
myList.append('X')
```

Comment: Read the question more carefully.

Comment: Actually `append` will insert an element only at the end. But OP wants to insert at index `1`.