# Is there a way to insert items in the beginning of a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have two questions about the Python list.

- Is there a way to insert items in the beginning and end of the python list? For instance, suppose that I have the list below

```
A = ["I","am","happy"]
```

What is the easiest way to generate the list `B` below from the list `A`, by specifying that I want the additional items to be at the beginning and at the end of the original list?

```
B = ["<bos>", "I", "am", "happy", "<eos>"]
```

- suppose now that I want to add a special token `<spec_token>` right before the token `am`. Is there a way to do so by specifying before which token (`am` in this case) I want to insert the `<spec_token>` at? So continuing from the previous example, I want to generate the list `C` below:

```
C = ["<bos>", "I", "<spec_token>", "am", "happy", "<eos>"]
```

Thank you,

PS: Please note that I do not want to use the token index as my parameter to insert a different token into the list. I want to use the specific tokens themselves as my parameter to update the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert an element at specific index in a list and return updated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-updated-list)

Comment: Please note that I don't want to use the index as the parameter to insert token. I want the specific token to be my parameter

Comment: _I do not want to use the token index as my parameter to insert a different token into the list._ Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should help you with any insert your looking to do:

```
 B.insert(B.index("am"), '<spec_token>')     

# ['<bos>', 'I', '<spec_token>', 'am', 'happy', '<eos>']
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be using `A.insert(index, value)`
So in your case, the statement would be

`A.insert(0, '<bos>')`