# How to insert element between 2 elements in a python list?

Tags: python, list

i have a list

```
my_list= [1,2,4,5]
```

i want to add 3 to the list, in between the 2 and the 4 so the list
becomes:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

how do i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert an element at specific index in a list and return updated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-updated-list)

Answer (score 4):

Use insert method to add element at specific index.
Syntax : `list.insert(i, elem)`

```
my_list.insert(2, 3) # inserting 3 at index 2.
```

to know more about insert method [Python List insert()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert)

Answer (score 2):

With `insert()`.

```
>>> my_list= [1,2,4,5]
>>> my_list.insert(2, 3)
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the index of 2(lower limit)
you can use

```
>>> index_of_2 = my_list.index(2) #gives you index of 2(lower limit)
>>> element_to_insert = 3
>>> my_list.insert(index_of_2 + 1, element_to_insert)
```