# defining an add function in python

Tags: python

I need help with defining an add function in python. This is my first time writing in python so I have trouble with a lot of the formatting. I need to define an add function for an arraylist that shifts one position all the items j>=i, insert an element at position i of the list and increment the number of elements in the list
Inputs:
i: Index that is integer non negative and at most n
x: Object type, i.e., any object
This is what I have written so far:

```
def add(self, i : int, x : object) :
    if i>0 & i<self.size():

        for n in range(i, self.size())

    else:
        pass
```

Now I wrote some psuedocode and was wondering if it would work:

```
def(add(self, i : int, x : object) :
  declare new empty array of size n+1
 if i>0 and i<=n:
   for(i to arr length):
    put i into new array
 else:
  pass
```

Comment: Are you creating your own arraylist class? You can easily achieve this using the insert method or list slices. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-a-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-the-updated-list)

Comment: You don't need reference to `self` here, this is not a class. And what exactly is `x` used for?

Comment: And is spelled `and` in Python.

Comment: What do you mean an "array list"? You mean a `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, basically python has this built in.

```
mylist.insert(index, element)
```

Answer (score 1):

so much trouble for something already built-in D:

```
lst.insert(index, element)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(self, iitems):
    self.items = iitems
    self.size = len(self.items)

def add(self, i, x):
    ret = self.items[:i]
    ret.append(x)
    ret.extend(self.items[i:])
    self.items = ret
    self.size += 1
```