# How to insert elements at a specific index in a list and return the updated list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say I got a list below:

```
original = ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

I want to add another list, called `add_item`, to the list `original`:

```
add_item = ['b', 'd']
```

The result should be:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: where's `d` gone?

Comment: ahhh! sorry.. i forgot to put the value `d` on ...

Comment: Define `add` please. Concatenate (append? prepend?)? Insert and keep sorted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert an element at a specific index in a list and return the updated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-a-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-the-updated-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
original = ['a', 'c', 'e']
add_item = ['b', 'd']
original.extend(add_item) #['a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original = ['a', 'c', 'e']
add_item = ['b', 'd']

print(sorted(original + add_item))
```

You can use the overloaded `+` operator to concatenate lists, and if sorting is important to you you can use the built-in `sorted` function

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically the cleanest way would be to use extend method

```py
original = ['a','c','e']
original.extend(add_item)
```