# How do I insert element to a list not by index in Python?

Tags: python

I want to insert new element into a list by value and not by index.
like:

```
list = [ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange']
```

I want to insert 'banana' before 'orange'

Comment: You should use Google before go to StackOverflow. There are bunch of tutorial about this that will be easier to understand than what we can answer here.

Comment: I didn't find..

Comment: Read [ask] and don't expect us to google this for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert an element at a specific index in a list and return the updated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-a-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-the-updated-list)

Comment: if not by index, then how? always same place, always last, 1st? please be precise

Comment: look.. I know append extend and insert
My qustation is how to insert an item by value because insert addt value by index

Comment: I think SO is more for specific questions for specific people, not just general questions. Also, make sure to search things up before asking about them because there might be an answer to your problem already.

Comment: If you can't use index, you can't do it (unless you want to place it at the last place).

Comment: what do you mean by "value" alphabetic order of the string? other value?

Answer (score 1):

A possible function is

```py
def insert_before(l, b, v):
    l.insert(l.index(b), v)
```

Then use it like this

```py
l = [ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange']
insert_before(l, "orange", "banana")
```

Comment: You shouldn't name a list to `list` because it the next time you want to convert a tuple to a list, it might think the `list` is `[ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange']`

Comment: Yes right, I modify it. I took the name used by the author.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command to do this.

You need to first find the index of the item before which you want to insert, like so:

```
lst = [ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange']

try:
    before = lst.index('organge')
except ValueError: #no banana in the list
    lst.append('orange')
```

Then insert it by the index you found:

```
lst.insert(before, 'banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is better to rename list

```
list1 = [ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange']
list1.insert(2,'banana')
print(list1)
```

Comment: @Szeverin wants to insert by specifying the value, not the index.

Comment: I said not by index.. I have to got the value which is 'orange'. I have to use orange and not 2 what is an index. Can't explain better